# Python: Combine multiple lists into one JSON array

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, dictionary, merge

I want to merge several lists into one JSON array. 
These are my two lists:

```
address =  ['address1','address2']
temp = ['temp1','temp2']
```

I combine both lists by the following call and create a JSON .

```
new_list = list(map(list, zip(address, temp)))
jsonify({
    'data': new_list
})
```

This is my result for the call:

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            "address1",
            "temp1"
        ],
        [
            "address2",
            "temp2"
        ]
    ]
}
```

However, I would like to receive the following issue. How do I do that and how can I insert the identifier `address` and `hello`.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "address": "address1",
            "temp": "temp1"
        },
        {
            "address": "address2",
            "temp": "temp2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list-comprehension:

```
import json

address =  ['address1','address2']
temp = ['temp1','temp2']

d = {'data': [{'address': a, 'temp': t} for a, t in zip(address, temp)]}

print( json.dumps(d, indent=4) )
```

Prints:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "address": "address1",
            "temp": "temp1"
        },
        {
            "address": "address2",
            "temp": "temp2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Cool as easy. I could have come up with that myself. Thank you very much for your help. Really great.

Answer (score 1):

You can just change your existing code like this. That `lambda` function will do the trick of converting it into a dict.

```
address =  ['address1','address2']
temp = ['temp1','temp2']

new_list = list(map(lambda x : {'address': x[0], 'temp': x[1]}, zip(address, temp)))

jsonify({
    'data': new_list
})
```