# Python creating JSON object from string

Tags: python, json, selenium

I'm new to Python and trying to generate a list of dictionaries in JSON format. I get the data from Selenium by iterating through an element. I get the output as string. Here's my selenium snippet:

```
Company = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='au-target company']")
Category = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='job-category']")
```

I get my data by using a for loop like this:

```
for value in Company:
    print(value.text)

for value in Category:
    print(value.text)
```

Here are my results:

```
Company A
Company B
Company C
Digital Technology
Manufacturing
Supply Chain
```

I would like to have my data in the following format

```
[
    {
        "Company": "Company A",
        "Category": "Digital Technology"
    },
    {
        "Company": "Company B",
        "Category": "Manufacturing"
    },
    {
        "Company": "Company C",
        "Category": "Supply Chain"
    }
]
```

So far I have been unsuccessful using the json module. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Combine multiple lists into one JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57475199/python-combine-multiple-lists-into-one-json-array)

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348640/two-lists-to-json-format-in-python/25348680

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle it like this

```
d = []
for company, category in zip(Company, Category):
    d.append({
        "company": company.text,
        "category": category.text
    })
```

or

```
d = [
    {"company": company.text, "category": category.text}
    for company, category in zip(Company, Category)
]
```

Comment: Thanks! I've gone with your first suggestion, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
data = []
for comp, cat in zip(Company, Category):
    data.append({'Company':comp, 'Category': cat})
```

---

**Output:**

```
data
[
    {
        "Company": "Company A",
        "Category": "Digital Technology"
    },
    {
        "Company": "Company B",
        "Category": "Manufacturing"
    },
    {
        "Company": "Company C",
        "Category": "Supply Chain"
    }
]
```